# MySQL permissions and privileges problems

Tags: permissions, mysql

I face a problem with the access to MySQL. I need to create and import a database but my default user have no necessary privileges to do it.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, additional details about OS and platform:

```
# uname -a
Linux improve1 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:36:54 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

This is my MySQL version:

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (i686) using  EditLine wrapper
```

The only user created (I was allowed to create only it) during installation is named "phpmyadmin".

If I make attempt to use this user privileges using phpMyAdmin (at http://localhost/phpmyadmin) I see "No Privileges"

If try to do it after console login I have the following problem:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE bulterm;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' to database 'bulterm'
```

When I check the privileges of this user I see the following:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for phpmyadmin@localhost                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost'                       |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `phpmyadmin`.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost'  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

But when I try to execute any operation like creating database, creating new user etc., I am restricted.

I want to create a MySQL user "root" with full privileges to do everything.

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: Lets confirm, is there any `root` user?  Please check with `mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost'`.

Comment: The result is even stranger than the problem itself: 
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Answer (score 2):

In three steps:

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

The middle steps will allow you to change the root password.

Comment: # dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7   RETURNS THE FOLLOWING
dpkg-query: package 'mysql-server-5.7' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server-5.7 is not installed

Comment: While typing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server`, use `Tab` keys to foreseen what's the `mysql-server` installed.

Comment: Sometimes you may have installed `mariadb-server` instead of `mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Login user **root** and password same you are using with your Mysql User

Phpmyadmin panel will open and follow the steps:

1) goto users
2) check if your user exists for mysql users

**User**    **Host**    **Password**    **Global** **privileges**   **Grant**   **Action**

3) click on Edit Privileges for specific **user**

4) Check **Mark** all global Privileges and **Go**

5) Login with your current user It will access to create and allow permission

Thanks..!!

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to login as root. I see the following: 
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 
Thanks for efforts!

Comment: Then go to  Ubuntu /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php .... check config file and find out  : $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;     Depending on distributions, there could be multiple occurrences of that particular line. Ubuntu for example has the following 2 lines;
if (!empty($dbname)) {
    // other configuration options
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
    // it should be placed before the following line
    $i++;
}
// other configuration options
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

Answer (score 1):

You need to open `phpmyadmin.conf` from the `dbconfig-common` folder and change the database user name from "phpmyadmin" to "root":

```
sudo gedit /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf 

# dbc_dbuser: database user
#       the name of the user who we will use to connect to the database.
dbc_dbuser='root'

# dbc_dbpass: database user password
#       the password to use with the above username when connecting
#       to a database, if one is required
dbc_dbpass='12345'
```