# No MySQL Privileges For Any Usr

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have searched previous posts for days now... and no solution seems to work, I am risking a "duplicate post"...

**PROBLEM:**  PHPMYADMIN installs flawlessly, but none of my users have even basic permissions (ie drop, create,grant,etc).  So I can't create my the dbs for wordpress and drupal on my localhost dev server.

basic info

Fresh install Ubuntu 18.04

```
Linux rider1 5.3.0-53-generic #47~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 13:10:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Apache2

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
```

MySQL 5.7

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

PHP 7

```
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 (cli) (built: May 26 2020 13:09:11) ( NTS )
```

**PROBLEM DETAILS:** I have two mysql users <kbd>root</kbd> and <kbd>phpmyadmin</kbd>, both should have "superuser" privileges, but each time I try to grant privileges and/or create a DB using either user via mysql, I get the following errors, respectively:

```
GRANT PRIVILEGES: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

CREATE DATABASE:  ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'wp_db'
```

**MYSTERY**

When I log into PHPMYADMIN via the browser the default dbs are missing are different for each user.  This is what I see for my `root` user:

[image]

**NOTE:**  Clicking `Check privileges` only results in a message confirming no privileges.

When I log into PHPMYADMIN as `phpmyadmin` user, this is what I see:
[image]

**NOTE:** Again, clicking <kbd>Check privileges</kbd> only results in a message stating that I have no privileges on the dbs.

Also inside of phpmyadmin, I do NOT have any <kbd>Users</kbd> or <kbd>Privileges</kbd> tabs to click on to add users and/or privileges.
[image]

Also, when I log into MySQL from the command line use the commands `SHOW GRANTS` and `SHOW DATABASES` for `root` and `phpmyadmin` users I get confirmation of the information shown in the screenshots above.

**SOLUTIONS that I have tried:**

1.) I installed LAMP via `tasksel` and confirmed it installed flawlessly with `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` and `sudo apache2ctl configtest`

2.) I have completely uninstalled, purged, and reinstalled phpmyadmin

3.) I confirmed that apache2 was properly configured to use phpmyadmin via `ls /etc/apache2/conf-available/` and `ls /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`

4.) I tried every suggested solution listed in reply to [similar question found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875634/mysql-permissions-and-privileges-problems). Including running:

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Which produced the following results:

```
myuser@mymachine:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
Checking if update is needed.
Checking server version.
Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
Checking system database.
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.engine_cost                                  OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.general_log                                  OK
mysql.gtid_executed                                OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats                           OK
mysql.innodb_table_stats                           OK
mysql.ndb_binlog_index                             OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
mysql.server_cost                                  OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.slave_master_info                            OK
mysql.slave_relay_log_info                         OK
mysql.slave_worker_info                            OK
mysql.slow_log                                     OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK
The sys schema is already up to date (version 1.5.2).
Checking databases.
phpmyadmin.pma__bookmark                           OK
phpmyadmin.pma__central_columns                    OK
phpmyadmin.pma__column_info                        OK
phpmyadmin.pma__designer_settings                  OK
phpmyadmin.pma__export_templates                   OK
phpmyadmin.pma__favorite                           OK
phpmyadmin.pma__history                            OK
phpmyadmin.pma__navigationhiding                   OK
phpmyadmin.pma__pdf_pages                          OK
phpmyadmin.pma__recent                             OK
phpmyadmin.pma__relation                           OK
phpmyadmin.pma__savedsearches                      OK
phpmyadmin.pma__table_coords                       OK
phpmyadmin.pma__table_info                         OK
phpmyadmin.pma__table_uiprefs                      OK
phpmyadmin.pma__tracking                           OK
phpmyadmin.pma__userconfig                         OK
phpmyadmin.pma__usergroups                         OK
phpmyadmin.pma__users                              OK
sys.sys_config                                     OK
Upgrade process completed successfully.
Checking if update is needed.
```

I have been reading other questions / solutions for 2 days and none of them match my LAMP / OS config with mysql 5.7 and ubuntu 18.04 and the overwhelming assume that the privileges of users work.

Anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CAUSE OF PROBLEM:**
If you are trying to install myphpadmin, run into whatever problems, then decide to completely uninstall phpmyadmin.... DO NOT select the "YES" when myphpmyadmin asks if you want to delete the related db's, user privileges, & configurations.  INSTEAD, select "NO", then un-installation is complete run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to get rid of the additiona software packages that were installed.

**IF YOU SELECT "YES" (cause of problem continued):**
What happens is that the un-installation process deletes an utterly vital directory necessary for mysql to work properly. Namely, `/var/run/mysqld`

To **RE-ESTABLISH** the vital directory, use the following command:

`sudo mkdir -v /var/run/mysqld && sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld`

After this command you should be able to re-establish your `root` user privileges using the following commands:

`sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &` , then
`sudo mysql -u root mysql` , and `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' with GRANT OPTION;` from the `mysql>` prompt..

**AT THIS POINT:** I decided to completely re-install phpmyadmin because even though I had superuser privileges restored, some of the default installation databases were still missing.  However, this time I selected "NO",when asked if I want to delete the default db's, user privileges, & configurations. Then I used `sudo apt-get autoremove phpmyadmin && sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin` to get rid of all of the additional packages that were installed.

Once I ran `sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext`,  `sudo phpenmod mbstring` , and `sudo phpenmod mbstring` phpmyadmin worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

If you miss privileges even on command line login then it's not PhpMyAdmin issue.
Did you try the solution below found on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges

Stop `mysqld` and restart it with the `--skip-grant-tables` option.
Connect to the `mysqld` server with just: `mysql` (i.e. no `-p` option, and username may not be required).

Issue the following commands in the mysql client:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After that, you should be able to run `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';` and have it work.

Comment: I am a bit of unix prompt newbie in regards to mysql.... can you post step by step commands?  thx

Comment: Example of confusion... what's the difference between 'mysqld' or 'mysql'?   When I use 'sudo service mysqld stop', I get an error message that no such service is found.  So I decide stop mysql using 'sudo service mysql stop'....  Also HOW do I connect to mysql.. because '(i.e. no -p option, and username may not be required)' in NOT clear.  Can you provide a specific command?  Because every time I try to  connect to mysql without -p option... I just get another error  (ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user )

Comment: PROGRESS: I ran the following commands
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
Then I received a message stating that the "UNIX socket file don't exists"
So then I ran:
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
THEN I ran:
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root   (no -p attribute & NO linux prompt -it seemed to be hanging be responded to my entry)
THEN I was ar the "mysql> " prompt and I was about to grant all privileges to my root user.  The BIG PROBLEM now... is that I can NOT restart mysql.... :-(

Comment: This is the error I get when trying to start mysql from the linux prompt:
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I assume you already installed MySQL server properly by running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install mysql-server`
Did you ever actually configure it by running `sudo mysql_secure_installation`?

Comment: I did not run `mysql_secure_installation` because I am building a local dev site and the tutorial said it was optional...as mentioned I used the 'tasksel' command `sudo tasksel install lamp-server` to install mysql... and tested that everything worked properly afterwards... only problem came while trying to install phpmyadmin...  in the comments today, I mentioned for whatever reason there was no Unix Socket directory found,,, so that is probably what was mucking things up...  can 'sudo mysql_secure_installation' help me start the mysql server again?

Comment: It will help you to reconfigure MySql server and set root password

Comment: Thanks for effort Taavi...  You get an "A" for effort... but the solution to the problem has nothing to do with your suggestion..  will post an answer shortly.

Comment: I don't think you understood the original problem based on your answer.  The answer that you offered would NOT work as long the missing directory 'mysqld' had not been re-created... re-read my my comment that starts with the word "PROGRESS".